# How to use vite for production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, vite

I'm new to Vite and trying to use this for production.
The question is how can i create scripts (used for docker) to run this on prod.

The documentation says the preview should not be used for production.

In that case, what i do is run `yarn build (tsc && vite build)` but what to run after ?

I'm looking for equivalent of `vite preview` but for production.

Sample docker:

```
FROM node:18 as build

WORKDIR /src/build

COPY package.json .

COPY . .

RUN yarn install \
&& yarn build

EXPOSE 3001

CMD ['SOME COMMAND INSTEAD OF PREVIEW']
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is use Vite to also serve the build files. Which is not ideal for production! Instead, you would want to use a web server to host those build files! Here's a resource (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-react-apps-to-production/) to sample deployment using the docker.

Comment: So just use `vite build` and point the server to use the build files right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Though I would suggest using one of these methods (https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html) to deploy than using docker!

Comment: None of the methods in the docs deploy to ECS on AWS

Comment: None of the methods in the docs suggest a way to deploy on Google Cloud Run either...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an image that only contains the final build artifacts and not all the bloated dependencies, you can use a two-stage Docker build. The Dockerfile below builds the artifacts using a Node.js image, then serves the generated content with a busybox httpd server.

```
FROM node:20-alpine AS build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM busybox:1.35
RUN adduser -D static
USER static
WORKDIR /home/static
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist .
CMD ["busybox", "httpd", "-f", "-v", "-p", "8080"]
```

Hope that helps!